# WordPress Archive dropdown selection doesn't save after refresh

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, archive

So I have Cyclone Slider plugin and where it's URL link I want to make Archive url's drop down to assign different picture to different archive month link.

My select dropdown looks like this:

```
<select id="<?php echo esc_attr( $dropdown_id ); ?>" name="cycloneslider_metas[<?php echo $i; ?>][link]" class="cycloneslider_metas_link_url widefat">
                <?php

                $dropdown_args = apply_filters( 'widget_archives_dropdown_args', array(
                    'type'            => 'monthly',
                    'format'          => 'option',
                    'show_post_count' => $c
                ) );
                ?>

                <?php wp_get_archives( $dropdown_args ); ?>

</select>
```

When I save with options I like, everything is working, and all pictures have the link that I assigned, but if I go back to that edit page again, every drop down is reset to the default option and I have to assign links again every time.

Why don't they save? What am I missing?